# References section at the bottom of a page

Tags: bibtex, positioning

I'm fairly new to Latex, but I'm writing a paper using Latex and Bibtex. In the end I have section with all the references I quoted:

```
\newpage
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Is it possible to place the references at the bottom of the previous page (there's enough space) rather than putting it on a whole new page? What command would that be?

Comment: Your `\newpage` command is forcing the page break. If you take this out it should go away.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In addition to Andrews answer: We need a full example which shows this page break. If we don't know, what documentclass you are using, we can't help. But as said before: `\newpage` will not make it easier... Post an example which is as short as possible but shows your described problem.

Comment: And if you want it flush to the page bottom, in addition to removing the `\newpage`, I think you could insert a `\vfill` prior to the `\bibliography`.  (As an aside, I also think the `\bibliographystyle` should precede the `\bibliography`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Five months late with the following comment, I'm afraid: It actually doesn't matter *where* in the document the instruction `\bibliographystyle` is inserted: in the preamble, in the body of the document but before `\bibliography`, or somewhere after `\bibliography`. LaTeX doesn't act on this instruction directly. All LaTeX does with it is to write the information to the aux file when `\end{document}` is encountered. During its separate run, BibTeX opens the aux file and looks for this piece of information; it doesn't care where in the aux file it may be provided.

Comment: @Mico I stand corrected... and five months later, boy am I tired.  Can I sit now?